# Selenium will not load full DOM tree, just the page source

Tags: python, selenium, innerhtml, webdriverwait, expected-exception

I have tried several answers in Stack Overflow. When I print the webpage I can only see the equivalent of viewing the page source in Chrome, rather than the full DOM tree you would get from inspecting the web page. As you can see I have put a wait in but this hasn't changed anything, should I try Firefox instead of Chrome?

Is it possible the website I'm trying to use has anti-scraping measures? What else could I try?

```
def selenium_start(url):
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
  driver.get(url)
  try:
    driver = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until\
    (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "koex")))
  except:
    print('Sorry!')
  return driver

webpage_driver = selenium_start('https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/')

"""
div_container = webpage_driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'maincontent')
html = webpage_driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')
#inner_div = div_container.get_attribute('outerHTML')
"""

print(page_soup)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

To extract the *Page Source* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` of an element within the [webpage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) and you can use the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.bd-title")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html lang="en"><head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Toggle the visibility of content across your project with a few classes and our JavaScript plugins.">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v3.7.0">

  <title>Collapse · Bootstrap</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

  <style class="anchorjs"></style><link href="/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Documentation extras -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="/docs/4.0/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#563d7c">
  <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#563d7c">


  <!-- Twitter -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@getbootstrap">
  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="@getbootstrap">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="Collapse">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="Toggle the visibility of content across your project with a few classes and our JavaScript plugins.">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-social-logo.png">

  <!-- Facebook -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Collapse">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Toggle the visibility of content across your project with a few classes and our JavaScript plugins.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-social.png">
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-social.png">
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="630">


  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-146052-10', 'getbootstrap.com');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>

    <script id="_carbonads_projs" type="text/javascript" src="https://srv.carbonads.net/ads/CKYIKKJL.json?segment=placement:getbootstrapcom&amp;callback=_carbonads_go"></script></head>
    <body>
      <a id="skippy" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">
        <div class="container">
      <span class="skiplink-text">Skip to main content</span>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/" class="d-block px-3 py-2 text-center text-bold text-white old-bv">There's a newer version of Bootstrap 4!</a>

  <header class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark flex-column flex-md-row bd-navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2" href="/" aria-label="Bootstrap"><svg class="d-block" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 612 612" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M510 8a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94 94v408a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94 94H102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94-94V102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94-94h408m0-8H102C45.9 0 0 45.9 0 102v408c0 56.1 45.9 102 102 102h408c56.1 0 102-45.9 102-102V102C612 45.9 566.1 0 510 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" d="M196.77 471.5V154.43h124.15c54.27 0 91 31.64 91 79.1 0 33-24.17 63.72-54.71 69.21v1.76c43.07 5.49 70.75 35.82 70.75 78 0 55.81-40 89-107.45 89zm39.55-180.4h63.28c46.8 0 72.29-18.68 72.29-53 0-31.42-21.53-48.78-60-48.78h-75.57zm78.22 145.46c47.68 0 72.73-19.34 72.73-56s-25.93-55.37-76.46-55.37h-74.49v111.4z"></path></svg>
  </a>

    <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Bootstrap');">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Docs');">Documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="/docs/4.0/examples/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Examples');">Examples</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://themes.getbootstrap.com/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Themes');" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Themes</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://expo.getbootstrap.com/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Expo');" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Expo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://blog.getbootstrap.com/" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Navbar', 'Community links', 'Blog');" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle mr-md-2" href="#" id="bd-versions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      v4.0
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="bd-versions">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/docs/4.1/">Latest (v4.1.x)</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item active" href="/docs/4.0/">v4.0.0</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/">v4 Alpha 6</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/">v3.3.7</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/">v2.3.2</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-2" href="https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="GitHub"><svg class="navbar-nav-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 499.36" focusable="false"><title>GitHub</title><path d="M256 0C114.64 0 0 114.61 0 256c0 113.09 73.34 209 175.08 242.9 12.8 2.35 17.47-5.56 17.47-12.34 0-6.08-.22-22.18-.35-43.54-71.2 15.49-86.2-34.34-86.2-34.34-11.64-29.57-28.42-37.45-28.42-37.45-23.27-15.84 1.73-15.55 1.73-15.55 25.69 1.81 39.21 26.38 39.21 26.38 22.84 39.12 59.92 27.82 74.5 21.27 2.33-16.54 8.94-27.82 16.25-34.22-56.84-6.43-116.6-28.43-116.6-126.49 0-27.95 10-50.8 26.35-68.69-2.63-6.48-11.42-32.5 2.51-67.75 0 0 21.49-6.88 70.4 26.24a242.65 242.65 0 0 1 128.18 0c48.87-33.13 70.33-26.24 70.33-26.24 14 35.25 5.18 61.27 2.55 67.75 16.41 17.9 26.31 40.75 26.31 68.69 0 98.35-59.85 120-116.88 126.32 9.19 7.9 17.38 23.53 17.38 47.41 0 34.22-.31 61.83-.31 70.23 0 6.85 4.61 14.81 17.6 12.31C438.72 464.97 512 369.08 512 256.02 512 114.62 397.37 0 256 0z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-2" href="https://twitter.com/getbootstrap" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Twitter"><svg class="navbar-nav-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 416.32" focusable="false"><title>Twitter</title><path d="M160.83 416.32c193.2 0 298.92-160.22 298.92-298.92 0-4.51 0-9-.2-13.52A214 214 0 0 0 512 49.38a212.93 212.93 0 0 1-60.44 16.6 105.7 105.7 0 0 0 46.3-58.19 209 209 0 0 1-66.79 25.37 105.09 105.09 0 0 0-181.73 71.91 116.12 116.12 0 0 0 2.66 24c-87.28-4.3-164.73-46.3-216.56-109.82A105.48 105.48 0 0 0 68 159.6a106.27 106.27 0 0 1-47.53-13.11v1.43a105.28 105.28 0 0 0 84.21 103.06 105.67 105.67 0 0 1-47.33 1.84 105.06 105.06 0 0 0 98.14 72.94A210.72 210.72 0 0 1 25 370.84a202.17 202.17 0 0 1-25-1.43 298.85 298.85 0 0 0 160.83 46.92" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-2" href="https://bootstrap-slack.herokuapp.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="Slack"><svg class="navbar-nav-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" focusable="false"><title>Slack</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M210.787 234.832l68.31-22.883 22.1 65.977-68.309 22.882z"></path><path d="M490.54 185.6C437.7 9.59 361.6-31.34 185.6 21.46S-31.3 150.4 21.46 326.4 150.4 543.3 326.4 490.54 543.34 361.6 490.54 185.6zM401.7 299.8l-33.15 11.05 11.46 34.38c4.5 13.92-2.87 29.06-16.78 33.56-2.87.82-6.14 1.64-9 1.23a27.32 27.32 0 0 1-24.56-18l-11.46-34.38-68.36 22.92 11.46 34.38c4.5 13.92-2.87 29.06-16.78 33.56-2.87.82-6.14 1.64-9 1.23a27.32 27.32 0 0 1-24.56-18l-11.46-34.43-33.15 11.05c-2.87.82-6.14 1.64-9 1.23a27.32 27.32 0 0 1-24.56-18c-4.5-13.92 2.87-29.06 16.78-33.56l33.12-11.03-22.1-65.9-33.15 11.05c-2.87.82-6.14 1.64-9 1.23a27.32 27.32 0 0 1-24.56-18c-4.48-13.93 2.89-29.07 16.81-33.58l33.15-11.05-11.46-34.38c-4.5-13.92 2.87-29.06 16.78-33.56s29.06 2.87 33.56 16.78l11.46 34.38 68.36-22.92-11.46-34.38c-4.5-13.92 2.87-29.06 16.78-33.56s29.06 2.87 33.56 16.78l11.47 34.42 33.15-11.05c13.92-4.5 29.06 2.87 33.56 16.78s-2.87 29.06-16.78 33.56L329.7 194.6l22.1 65.9 33.15-11.05c13.92-4.5 29.06 2.87 33.56 16.78s-2.88 29.07-16.81 33.57z" fill="currentColor"></path></svg>
  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <a class="btn btn-bd-download d-none d-lg-inline-block mb-3 mb-md-0 ml-md-3" href="https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.0.0.zip">Download</a>
  </header>


      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row flex-xl-nowrap">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 bd-sidebar">
        <form class="bd-search d-flex align-items-center">
    <span class="algolia-autocomplete" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr;"><input type="search" class="form-control ds-input" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search for..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top;"><pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;"></pre><span class="ds-dropdown-menu" role="listbox" id="algolia-autocomplete-listbox-0" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; z-index: 100; display: none; left: 0px; right: auto;"><div class="ds-dataset-1"></div></span></span>
    <button class="btn btn-link bd-search-docs-toggle d-md-none p-0 ml-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bd-docs-nav" aria-controls="bd-docs-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle docs navigation"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30" focusable="false"><title>Menu</title><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22"></path></svg>
  </button>
  </form>
  .
  <div class="bd-example">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
  .       
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px;">Name</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Type</th>
        <th style="width: 50px;">Default</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>parent</td>
        <td>selector | jQuery object | DOM element </td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td>If parent is provided, then all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown. (similar to traditional accordion behavior - this is dependent on the <code>card</code> class). The attribute has to be set on the target collapsible area.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>toggle</td>
        <td>boolean</td>
        <td>true</td>
        <td>Toggles the collapsible element on invocation</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  .
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 150px;">Event Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>show.bs.collapse</td>
        <td>This event fires immediately when the <code>show</code> instance method is called.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>shown.bs.collapse</td>
        <td>This event is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hide.bs.collapse</td>
        <td>This event is fired immediately when the <code>hide</code> method has been called.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hidden.bs.collapse</td>
        <td>This event is fired when a collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="bd-clipboard"><button class="btn-clipboard" title="" data-original-title="Copy to clipboard">Copy</button></div><figure class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-js" data-lang="js"><span class="nx">$</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'#myCollapsible'</span><span class="p">).</span><span class="nx">on</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'hidden.bs.collapse'</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="kd">function</span> <span class="p">()</span> <span class="p">{</span>
    <span class="c1">// do something…</span>
  <span class="p">})</span></code></pre></figure>


      </main>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

  <script src="/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/docsearch.js@2/dist/cdn/docsearch.min.js"></script><script src="/docs/4.0/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>


  </body></html>
  ```

Comment: I put a wait line in my code already, I already have the source but I'm trying to get the full DOM tree. Also ignore that url, sorry that is not the real one.

Comment: @Gabriel `presence_of_element_located()` doesn't ensures visibility of element, so you need to use `visibility_of_element_located()`. Checkout the updated ans wer and let me know the status. Additionally, Do you define [full DOM tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) differently?

Comment: can you explain the wait for By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.bd-title"? What shall I wait for in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the DOM nodes you are looking for are inside iframes. In that case, you need to look for them inside those iframes by:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
for pos, iframe in enumerate(iframes):
    src = iframe.get_attribute('src')
    
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    # driver = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "...")))
    
    source = getattr(driver, "page_source", "no page source")
    print(pos, src, len(source), source[:1000])
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to tell from context but if you have a string containing the page html source then parsing it with Beautiful Soup will do. Maybe not ideal if you need to keep the number of dependencies as small as possible but thats an easy fix.

Comment: I have done this, but lots of the elements from the html body are missing. All the ones I need in this case.