# Selenium Python - "No such element: Unable to locate element" locating an input element within an iframe with headless chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, app-store-connect, google-chrome-headless

Hi I've been stuck for awhile on automating login for apple appstore as I am trying to make it headless without seeing the browser on execution.The problem is on execution with headless option and other options overall it doesn't find the field for appleid saying:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="account_name_text_field"]"}
```

This is the code I tried so far:

```
options = selenium_chrome()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--verbose')
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "download.default_directory": DOWNLOAD_DIR,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login')
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
time.sleep(10)
   
f = driver.find_element_by_id("aid-auth-widget-iFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame(f)
# driver.implicitly_wait(15)
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_id('account_name_text_field').send_keys('appleid')
driver.find_element_by_id("sign-in").click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_id('remember-me').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('password_text_field').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_id("sign-in").click()
```

Notes:

1. I have tried getting the XPATH and CSS selectors instead of the ID and the result was the same.
2. Instead of `time.sleep()` I tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='account_name_text_field']"))).send_keys('appleid')
```

and the result was `TimeoutException`

3. Did a retry function,whenever the field is not found to keep trying until it is found, but that was kind of a bad approach and it didn't worked.

So I am out of ideas what causes this behavior,the field is being found without the options for selenium and it logins fine visually, but whenever options are being added it doesn't find the input text field for `appleid` anymore... Might be an Apple thing that I don't know.

Comment: So, it finds the element of you remove the "headless " option ?

Comment: When selenium runs visually(without any option) it finds the element and it logins fine. Adding headless and other options seems to fail to find the element

Comment: does this help you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316810/unable-to-locate-elements-on-webpage-with-headless-chrome

Comment: No, I tried that as well even though I'm using a similar option for safe browsing in the question.

Comment: Are you able to identify which exact options aprt from "headless ", is giving you this error ?

Comment: @PSR I commented all of the options and left only `options = selenium_chrome()`. Seems having `options` as `chrome_options` in driver is enough to give this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` element with the placeholder as ***Apple ID*** is within an [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#account_name_text_field"))).send_keys("mastaofthepasta")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='aid-auth-widget-iFrame']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='account_name_text_field']"))).send_keys("mastaofthepasta")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: appleStoreConnect]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

---

### Update

When you use [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) and print the [*page_source*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072138/selenium-will-not-load-full-dom-tree-just-the-page-source/60073315#60073315) the output on the console is:

```
<html><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>Apple</center>


<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
</body></html>
```

---

### 403 Forbidden

The HTTP [`403 Forbidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to [`401`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but for the ***403 Forbidden*** status code re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

---

### Conclusion

[ChromeDriver initiated *Chrome Browser* gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191) as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) and further navigation is blocked.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Website denies get request using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62978920/website-denies-get-request-using-selenium/62982909#62982909)
- [How to fix 403 response when using HttpURLConnection in Selenium since the links are opening manually without any issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668773/how-to-fix-403-response-when-using-httpurlconnection-in-selenium-since-the-links/56670134#56670134)

Comment: This throws a `TimeoutException`

Comment: For what code line?

Comment: When sending the keys. When it is being run without the options it works fine and you can see visually how the login is successful, but whenever options are being added to work in headless mode and other options it doesn't find the element or timeouts with the code that you provided.

Comment: @mastaofthepasta Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Connection was refused - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Comment: [Errno 111 - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686968/maxretryerror-httpconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded-caused-by-protocolerror/52701504#52701504) is a much broader error.

Comment: That worked! Removing `driver.quit()` fixes the connection error and regarding the 403 it seems proxy has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is here:
Instead of

```py
options.add_argument('headless')
```

It should be

```py
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

i.e. you are missing `--` before the option argument
**UPD**
Instead of

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```

It could be

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver', options=options)
```

Comment: That was a typo, but didn't change anything

Comment: This typo could cause problems..

Comment: As mentioned by PSR, try removing all the unnecessary options. Leave only `('--headless')` and `('--window-size=1920x1080')` and remove all the others for now and see if this makes your code work better

Comment: Tried that as well... as with little options, with more options and no options. The only working way is with no options...