# My selenium program can't find anything, how do I fix that?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web, web-scraping

I can't find any element. Even The function .page_source returns only : ""
I am coding on google colab.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
proxy_ip_port = "64.235.204.107:3128"
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities = capabilities)

wd.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')

html = wd.page_source
print(html)
```

and the outcome is :

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried https instead of http?

Comment: Turn off headless option, see what happens when you navigate to that page. Are you sure proxy works?

Comment: @Ouss I did try https, same result

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 that is the thing, I am working on google colab so I can't turn off the headless option. And I am forced to work on colab because I don't know why but my Mac won't install correctly PIP

Comment: Are you sure your proxy works as intended? Did you try another proxy?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 I just tried a few other proxies it was indeed the problem ! thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

To extract the [*page source*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073315/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) for a static element as an example the **IPv4** element and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.address#ipv4")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://whatismyipaddress.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='address' and @id='ipv4']")))
  print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <html lang="en-US" class="chrome chrome103 wf-loading wf-montserrat7copensans3a3002c4002c6002c800-n4-loading" style="overflow-x: hidden;"><head>
  <style id="style_whatismyipaddress_leaderboard_dynamic">
              div[name='whatismyipaddress_leaderboard_dynamic']:not(div[id*='_slot']) {
                  display: flex;
                  align-items: center;
                  justify-content: center;
                  min-height: 90px !important;
              }
          </style><script async="" src="//c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/apstag.js"></script><script async="" src="//confiant-integrations.global.ssl.fastly.net/gptprebidnative/202207121816/wrap.js"></script><script src="//js-sec.indexww.com/ht/p/184310-82987131453484.js"></script><script src="https://freestar-io.videoplayerhub.com/gallery.js"></script><script>window.confiant = window.confiant || {};
          window.confiant.prebidNameSpace='fsprebid';
          window.confiant.callback = function(blockingType, blockingId, isBlocked, wrapperId, tagId, impressionData) {
          postMessage({
            'message': 'CONFIANT_BLOCK',
            'prebid': impressionData.prebid,
            'dfp': impressionData.dfp,
          })};</script><script src="https://pghub.io/js/pandg-sdk.js"></script><meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <title>What Is My IP Address - See Your Public Address - IPv4 &amp; IPv6</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/">

  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/fr/mon-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/de/meine-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/es/mi-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/tr/ip-im">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/pl/moj-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-cn" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/zh-cn/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-tw" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/zh-tw/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-hk" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/zh-tw/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/ja/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="it" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/it/il-mio-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="vi" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/vi-vn/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="id" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/id/ip-saya">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="ru" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/ru/index">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/pt/meu-ip">
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://whatismyipaddress.com/nl/mijn-ip">


  <!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v12.4 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
  <meta name="description" content="Find out what your public IPv4 and IPv6 address is revealing about you! My IP address information shows your location; city, region, country, ISP and location on a map. Many proxy servers, VPNs, and Tor exit nodes give themselves away.">
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:title" content="What Is My IP Address? IP Address Tools and More">
  <meta property="og:description" content="IP address lookup, location, proxy detection, email tracing, IP hiding tips, blacklist check, speed test, and forums. Find, get, and show my IP address.">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://whatismyipaddress.com/">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="WhatIsMyIPAddress">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="IP address lookup, location, proxy detection, email tracing, IP hiding tips, blacklist check, speed test, and forums. Find, get, and show my IP address.">
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="What Is My IP Address? IP Address Tools and More">
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://whatismyipaddress.com/wp-content/uploads/concern-security.svg">
  .   
  .   
  </div></div></body></html>
  ```